# Windows installer using GRUB - is on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, self-answer

As I work as a technician, often I need to install Windows.

I use my own method to create a multiboot USB using GRUB.

I have managed to create a USB (16GB) with three Windows (Windows 7 BIOS, Windows 10 32 bits BIOS, Windows 10 64 bits EFI).

I want to share this with the community, creating a question and answering it myself, having in mind that maybe lots of users share my type of work.

Since the method involves installing GRUB to a USB, and it's not really a Windows *problem* (IMHO) I was wondering if this would be considered on topic, or rather would be better suited to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com), and if it's a good idea to self-answer.

Comment: Relating https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4806/117549

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first instinct is that it wouldn't really be on topic, no. GRUB isn't a *nix thing, as such, it acts before the operating system so isn't really a part of any OS. Yes, it is a tool more commonly found in the *nix world, but using GRUB to install Windows systems doesn't seem to be something that would fall within the scope of this site.

It would, however, be very much on topic on Super User, yes. So I think it would be better to post it there. Also, self-answering is absolutely fine. More than fine, it is [actively encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132887/203101).

So my vote is for posting it on Super User. But please don't take this as The Law, I'm just giving my opinion as a user, not laying down the Word of Mod. If the community decides differently, that's fine by me.

Comment: I guess you are right. But since I'm a Linux user, and therefore I have more affinity with the Linux community, I prefer to share my knowledge with Linux users that have to deal with the Windows world.

Comment: @guillermochamorro actually, [su] isn't Windows only. There's a lot of *nix there as well. Hell, I have more than 40k rep there and I don't know anything about Windows. It's precisely because SU is OS-agnostic that I think this would be better there. That's where I'd expect to find Linux users who need to deal with the Windows world.

Comment: I solved it posting in SU the method for Windows, and in U&L the variant exclusively for Linux distros. Thanks!